# Conjugating the Lyness 5-cycle into a rotation of the plane

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

The Lyness 5-cycle is the map that sends $(x,y)$ to $(y,z)$ with $z=(y+1)/x$.  Leaving aside the set on which the map is not well-defined, the map is of order 5 (hence its name).  Is there an algebraic map that conjugates the map to a rotation by 72 degrees?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this map is conjugate to an automorphism of $\mathbf{P}^2$. See

A. Beauville, J. Blanc, [*On Cremona transformations of prime order*](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0402037), C.R. Acad. Sci. Paris 339 (2004), no4, 257-259.

See also T. de Fernex, *On planar Cremona maps of prime order*, Nagoya Math. Journal, Vol. 174 (2004), 1–28, which contains a classification of planar Cremona maps of prime order up to conjugation. According to Remark 1.3.4 therein, the fact above was already known to Iskovskikh.

Comment: The reference is definitely helpful, especially the explicit formulas on page 3.  However, I don't know how to explicitly see the map $(x:y:z) \mapsto (x(z-y):z(x-y):xz)$ (the birational transformation that Beauville and Blanc treat) as being conjugate to the map $(x:y:z) \mapsto (xy:(y+z)z:xz)$ (the projective version of the Lyness 5-cycle map).

Comment: @James : Let $f : (x,y) \mapsto (y,\frac{y+1}{x})$ and $g : (x,y) \mapsto (1-y,1-\frac{y}{x})$. Then $g=hfh^{-1}$ with $h(x,y)=(-x,y+1)$. I didn't check this, but I knew the result had to be true since both maps are related to the functional equation of the dilogarithm :) By the way, the first versions of Beauville's article on arxiv use this functional equation to prove the result.

Comment: @Francois: That answers my question.  Thanks!