# Conjugating the tropical Lyness 5-cycle into a rotation of the plane

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, tropical-geometry

In his response to my question [Conjugating the Lyness 5-cycle into a rotation of the plane](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/110846/conjugating-the-lyness-5-cycle-into-a-rotation-of-the-plane), Francois Brunault provided an explicit conjugacy between the Lyness order-5 map and a 72-degree rotation, viewed as birational maps of projective 2-space.

However, Brunault’s map $g$ is not subtraction-free, so it does not tropicalize. So it is not clear to me whether the order-5 map of the plane to itself that sends $(x,y)$ to $(y,z)$ with $z = \max(y,0) - x$ is conjugate to a 72-degree rotation of the plane via a continuous piecewise linear conjugacy. Perhaps this is the same as asking whether the associated maps of tropical projective 2-space are conjugate via an automorphism of tropical projective 2-space.